# Asterisk Realtime keep updating NAT value as yes

Tags: asterisk

Asterisk 11 Realtime keep updating NAT value as yes in MySQL database. I followed this web page to integrate Asterisk Realtime. http://www.open-voip.org/index.php?title=Asterisk_Full_RealTime_example It worked fine, and I was trying to save NAT value as "force_rport,comedia" in sip_buddies table.

When I create a user, I always insert "force_rport,comedia" in NAT column. However, it automatically changes to "yes" after few hours. I checked sip.conf and default value was like this.

```
nat=force_rport,comedia
```

Is there a way to stop updating NAT value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed canreinvite value to "no" from "yes", and it is working now..

```
canreinvite = no
```

Answer (score 0):

Asterisk not dooing that

Check your scripts